# Angularjs - Fire button2's click event by clicking button1 (fake upload button)

Tags: angularjs

To replace ugly file upload button with stylish fake upload button, I use jquery as below.

**HTML**

```
<input type='file' name='file' class='file_upload_btn' style='display:none'>
<button class='fake_upload_btn'>Upload Files</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.fake_upload_btn').click(function() {
    $('.file_upload_btn').click();
})
```

Now what if I want do the same in Angularjs, without Jquery library dependency.

Answer (score 7):

It is kind of workaround , and i have checked it only in chrome but try this:

```
<label for="uploader">
   <button class='fake_upload_btn'>Upload Files</button>
   <input id="uploader" type='file' name='file' class='file_upload_btn' style='display:none' />
</label>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/84Xxb/

Click event on `button` is catched like a click on `label` and consequently `input` is also "clicked"!

UPDATE: But if you want a really "Angulary" solution , you need to use directives, like this:

```
app.directive('uploader', function () {
    return {
      template: "Upload Files <input type='file' name='file' class='file_upload_btn' style='display:none'>",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {   
        element.bind("click", function(){
          element.find("input")[0].click();
        });
      }
   }
});
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/DVALMH?p=preview

Comment: I checked this on firefox, IE9, IE10 and chrome. It's working like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: @user1995997 great , it will be helpful for me too!

Comment: Still not working for all browsers, So it's truly workaround. Maybe there is some angular way to do this.